# Z-Axis Coordination in WebGL and Three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse, webgl, three.js

I'm experimenting with WebGL and Three.js,
But how to calculate the Z-Axis coordination while moving mouse?

I use this for X and Y:

```
  function getCoord(e) {
      X = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      Y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
  }
```

how to get Z coordination?

Edit: I find this example, but can't figure it out myself...
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_voxelpainter.html

Thanks

Comment: I find the answer, but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to answer my question...here is the answer: http://catchvar.com/threejs-game-transforming-isometric-screen-co

Comment: Strange that SO doesn't let you answer your question. Maybe you have to have a certain amount of rep first?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer...

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     mouse2D.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
     mouse2D.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

function render() {
     mouse3D = projector.unprojectVector( mouse2D.clone(), camera );
...
```

Comment: You do realize you can accept your own answer? Please do so. :)